# Why does uploading documents through Google API give an error in http request header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to upload the document using Google API through my iPhone App. Here is the code which I am using:

```
NSString *authorizationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=\"%@\"" ,[another  objectAtIndex:1]]; 
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full"]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url2];
[urlRequest2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[urlRequest2 setValue:@"2.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"]; 
[urlRequest2 setValue:authorizationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[urlRequest2 setValue:Length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
[urlRequest2 setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[urlRequest2 setValue:slugStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Slug"]; 
[urlRequest2 setHTTPBody:audioData];
```

Where authorizationHeader contains my GoogleLogin auth=theToken

By running this code I get the following response from the server

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> <TITLE>Token invalid</TITLE>
</HEAD> 
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> 
<H1>Token invalid</H1> 
<H2>Error 401</H2> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

I don't know where I am making the mistake. Is there an error in my header or am I passing the wrong parameters?

Comment: "Token invalid" have made sure that `authorizationHeader` is producing a valid Authorization header string?

Comment: authorizationHeader variable cantain this string GoogleLogin auth=DQAAALwAAABr-yEKe01WT4DsIBRcBi2_RMEU2oRKJDU1DJ2A9_YfhYZf1lXmVs5b_9bVqGashnSSS1ljIGi4XWd3l9DO8‌​TLT4w24qDeKxS342bprl0Nyn5cFrdNdSfF3-YzudqIMYC1Xkf-b2VjARp-fWYU3Qhta6QN4tXaRHkFGnf1BEzGVrQVJd3EE987RWmC3qFy52X5lbybRmXPGRsJJ6msH6WhRZkg5UrN‌​9S5jPrMtVQfJlpAv4slExwsMo6TTDZEfZXVc

Comment: This is different. In the link you post OAuth is used and i'm using client login and that's in java i'm doing it in objective c.

Comment: it seems that your token is invalid

Comment: the token is returned by the google so it can't be unvlaid. There might be some thing i'm missing in the header or what. Don't know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the url in the is prefixed with **http://** when creating the NSURL?

```
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full"];
```